# Organic Based Photocathode

Tags: organic-chemistry, electrons, photochemistry, semiconductors

What organic molecules have a relatively small work function, preferably in the visible spectrum? Polycyclic aromatic hydrocarbons are in the low UV spectrum, making it unsuitable for the photocathode requirement. A work function in the green-cyan spectrum, or anything below3 eV is the main focus. Efficiency, thermal stability, etc is not the main focus for the time being

Comment: Look online for conjugated polymers. (I don't embark in a discussion or rant on the cons of using solid state physics concepts and *words* because it is a lost battle).

Comment: Also it will be useful to have a frame.

Comment: A work function in the green-cyan spectrum, or anything below3 eV is the main focus. Efficiency, thermal stability, etc is not the main focus for the time being

Comment: I don't know any. An organic with a very low oxidation potential & availability is PEDOT. In it oxidised form it can be cast in film having a work function similar to gold. I am not aware of HOMO levels lying higher than that in readily handled organics. But shall be the cathode be photoactive? Your question isn't that clear.

Comment: PEDOT has a work function of 5 eV, well into the UV spectrum. The main goal is a work function of 3 eV of below, all other factors are not of importance for the time being.

Comment: Therefore I said PEDOT has already a very low oxidation potential. It seems you are looking for an organic comparable to alkali metals!!!!